# installing lapack for scipy on win7, can't find make.inc

Tags: python, windows, scipy, lapack

I'm doing what this page says:

http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html

but, I can't find LAPACK\INSTALL\make.inc.LINUX, I also don't understand how to "Copy the file LAPACK\INSTALL\make.inc.LINUX to LAPACK\make.inc"

[can't find makeinc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSib1.jpg)

thank you. I also want to know, what is the easiest way to install scipy on win7, python 2.7.6?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install `scipy` (and other packages with several dependencies) on windows is through the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages] provided by [Christoph Gohlk](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/).

If you install  is [Numpy+MKL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) from this repo, it is already linked to the Intel Math Kernel Library, which includes LAPACK. After that, it will be easier to install scipy, either through one of these packages or `pip`.

Comment: I tried, but can't.... I tried "pip install whl" but failed, it said "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement whl no matching distribution found for whl". I tried "easy_install" but it said "could not find suitable distribution for requirement.parse('whl')". I also tried to change "whl" into "zip", then enter the folder and "python setup.py install", it said "no module named scipy._lib.six"

Comment: @hvchys instead of _whl_ put the actual path to the file that you downloaded. Something like `pip install c:\hvchys\scipy-xpto-123.whl`